# Negative lookbehinds in ActionScript

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, emoticons, negative-lookbehind

Im trying to write a Regex that will match most common emoticons, but not if they are inside a link.

- My emoticons are `:P` `=P` `:-P` `=-P` `:)` `:-)` `=)` `=-)` `:/` `=/` `:-/` `=-/` `:o` `=o` `:-o` `=-o` `:(` `:-(` `=(` `=-(` `:D` `:d` `:-D` `:-d` `=D` `=d` `=-D` `=-d`
- I don't want `http://` to match an emoticon in the `:/`
- I also don't want `http://something.com?feature=player` to cause an emoticon in the `:p`
- I can't use spaces as delimiters because I would like people to be able to type multiple emoticons back to back like this: `:):):)`

My current regular expression which is **almost** working is this:

```
(?<!http)([:=]{1}-?[\)\/\(ODP\]\[\\])|(;(-)?\))
```

The problem is that only the first emoticon match is omitted in a link, not all of them.

I've been using [Grant Skinner's Regexr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) to test.

Answer (score 1):

Matching all URLs in a regular expression is in itself a very complex task... perhaps, unless you feel especially challenged, not worth of attempting. It would be much easier to write a function that parses what you need. However, a good approximation of what a URL is might be the `/\w+([-+]\w+)*:[^\s]+/` (some examples to give you a better idea to why it is so: `svn+ssh://localhost`, `ftp://site_name.ouch.auch/~directory/?paramter:=)#anch:o)r`, `https://Новости-Советского-Информ-Бюро.рф/С%25Новым%25Годом!`). All of these are valid URLs :)

So, my tactics would be to first eliminate what seems like it is potentially a URL (this will, some times also catch smiles, because users may eventually create a valid URL by writing a smiley), and parse the rest.

Comment: That's true and I'm not super interested in the edge cases. At this point I'd simply like to match expression not preceded by an "http"

Comment: the problem with that approach is that I want the user to be able to type :):):):) and get 4 smileys

Answer (score 0):

Try pattern

```
(?:(?<!http)(?<!http:):/(?![a-zA-Z0-9])|:-/|=-?/|[:=]-?[()]|[:=]-?[PDdo](?!$)(?![a-zA-Z0-9=]))
```

Comment: @Ωmega now no emoticons match by themselves